# How to setup MySQL with cloud-init?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, cloud-init

How can I do this?

```
#cloud-config

users:
  - name: dev
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa AB3NzaC1yc...
    sudo: ['ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL']
    groups: sudo
    shell: /bin/bash

packages:
  - mysql-client
  - libmysqlclient-dev
  - mysql-server

package-update: true
package_upgrade: true

runcmd:

#
# SSH
#
  - sed -i -e '/^Port/s/^.*$/Port 22/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  - sed -i -e '/^PermitRootLogin/s/^.*$/PermitRootLogin no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  - sed -i -e '/^PasswordAuthentication/s/^.*$/PasswordAuthentication no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  - sed -i -e '$aAllowUsers dev' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

  - sudo service ssh restart

#
# Firewall
#

  # defaults
  - sudo ufw default deny incoming
  - sudo ufw default allow outgoing

  # exceptions
  - sudo ufw allow ssh
  - sudo ufw allow http
  - sudo ufw allow https

  # start on boot
  - sed -i -e '/^ENABLED/s/^.*$/ENABLED=yes/' /etc/ufw/ufw.conf

  - sudo ufw enable
```

With this configuration, **the root account is disabled**. And I get access **remote access with my `dev` user account**.

However, **MySQL installations fails** with:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Cloud-init v. 0.7.8 running 'modules:final' at Sun, 29 Jan 2017 12:09:56 +0000. Up 14.23 seconds.
2017-01-29 12:11:24,114 - util.py[WARNING]: Failed to install packages: ['mysql-client', 'libmysqlclient-dev', 'mysql-server']
2017-01-29 12:11:24,125 - cc_package_update_upgrade_install.py[WARNING]: 1 failed with exceptions, re-raising the last one
2017-01-29 12:11:24,128 - util.py[WARNING]: Running module package-update-upgrade-install (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_package_update_upgrade_install' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_package_update_upgrade_install.py'>) failed
```

If I don't specify any user, and perform a **typical setup** through apt-get **the installation runs fine**.

Is it not possible to **setup MySQL with cloud-init while having my root account disabled**? And if not, can I somehow tell **cloud-init to setup my users after my packages have been installed/updated**?

Comment: I usually setup MySQL using only a sudo account. However I am not familiar with `cloud-init` to give you a more meaningful answer.

Comment: You're right. I've updated my question not to question that possibility. I'm able to perform these steps manually without cloud-init, and all goes well. And with cloud-init, without specifying any users it successfully installs, also. So i'm pointing toward something related to account privileges at this point...maybe a farfetched guess though.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to overcome this issue by manually setting up the mysql-server with:

```
runcmd:
  - sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server
```

Anyone with the same issue will probably also want to take a look into installing mysql non-interactively.

```
runcmd:
  - echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password pwd" | sudo debconf-set-selections
  - echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password pwd" | sudo debconf-set-selections

  - sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server
```

Solution originally posted [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-setup-mysql-with-cloud-init)